# Sharing Link on Facebook Wall

Tags: html, facebook, metadata

I'm trying to share in my Facebook wall a personal link and it's showing this image. I tried to modify metadata, etc in my website, but still same problem. Please any suggestion to fix it, thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Use the sharing debugger and then scrape the page again to update it.

Also make sure to use the property: 'og:image' on the image you want to show.